# как в environment JENKINS передать переменную?

Tags: администрирование, jenkins, devops, jenkins-pipeline

у меня есть параметр($class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter' -----> ptr) он выбирается при запуске джобы, и  я хочу чтобы этот параметр присваивался переменной в environment {callback = ptr}, но  джоба выдает ошибку, типа используйте кавычки или функцию. как реализовать это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вызвал функцию  environment {callback = ptr(params.ptr)}, которую подключил в динамической библиотеки, она принимает параметр и чисто его выводит, все работает.